# Swagger: File Upload Button not showing

Tags: c#, file, button, upload, swagger

I'm trying to create a POST endpoint that will allow me to upload a single File in an API. I'm using swagger.

The problem is: no matter what I do, the "upload button" is not shown in my Swagger page.

This is my controller API post call:

```
        [HttpPost("{groupId:int:min(1)}/validate")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status502BadGateway)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument(IFormFile file)
        {
            // TODO: handle file upload
            return await Task.FromResult(Ok());
        }
```

I have a FileUploadFilter that written like this:

```
public class FileUploadFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var formParameters = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
                .Where(paramDesc => paramDesc.IsFromForm());

            if (formParameters.Any())
            {
                // already taken care by swashbuckle. no need to add explicitly.
                return;
            }
            if (operation.RequestBody != null)
            {
                // NOT required for form type
                return;
            }
            if (context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post.Method)
            {
                var uploadFileMediaType = new OpenApiMediaType() {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema() {
                        Type = "object",
                        Properties =
                        {
                        ["files"] = new OpenApiSchema()
                        {
                            Type = "array",
                            Items = new OpenApiSchema()
                            {
                                Type = "string",
                                Format = "binary"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                        Required = new HashSet<string>() { "files" }
                    }
                };

                operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody {
                    Content = { ["multipart/form-data"] = uploadFileMediaType }
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Helper
    {
        internal static bool IsFromForm(this ApiParameterDescription apiParameter)
        {
            var source = apiParameter.Source;
            var elementType = apiParameter.ModelMetadata?.ElementType;

            return (source == BindingSource.Form || source == BindingSource.FormFile)
                || (elementType != null && typeof(IFormFile).IsAssignableFrom(elementType));
        }
    }
```

and I'm injecting it into the Swagger Definition like this:

```
c.OperationFilter<FileUploadFilter>();
```

No matter what I do, the produces swagger page presents me with the following:

- A "path" parameter named "groupId"
- A request body that does not have an "upload button" and just says: file string($binary)

How can I display an "upload button" in my swagger home page? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I was not "hitting" the "try it out" button. My bad. It works like a charm